# What is happening when you declare an XNamespace and assign a string value?

Tags: c#, xnamespace

Here is the example from MSDN for XNamespace:

```
XNamespace aw = "http://www.adventure-works.com";
XElement root = new XElement(aw + "Root", "Content");
Console.WriteLine(root);
```

I am not sure what is happening in the first line.  Is there some kind of implicit conversion going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XNamespace` has a static `Get` method that accepts a string parameter and returns an `XNamespace` instance. So you could rewrite the line as

```
XNamespace aw = XNamespace.Get("http://www.adventure-works.com");
```

In the version you posted, you would be taking advantage of an [implicit conversion defined against string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.op_implicit.aspx). Presumably, the implementation thereof simply invokes the aforementioned method. An example of a *possible* implementation:

```
public static implicit operator XNamespace(string name)
{
    return Get(name);
}
```